# Android: track invisible for switchcompat when on white background

Tags: java, android, user-interface, switch-statement

I have an activity whose background is white, and I added a switchcompat, however when the switch is not active (off) the track is invisible. All that is visible is the thumb so it isn't obvious to the user that it's a switch at all. How can I make the switch's track visible when the switch is in the de-active position?

```
                    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                        android:id="@+id/someswitchname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        />
```

Comment: the color of the off track is something like `android:colorForeground` make sure your theme does not set it to `white`, or set it to another color.

Comment: @njzk2 - thanks for your help. android:colorForeground does indeed change the color of the track.. however I am unable to put a lighter colored thumb on a darker colored track - instead no matter what I set in foreground it insists on setting a darker thumb on a lighter track. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: this is probably because of the theme you use. what is the theme or your activity?

Comment: @njzk2 I'm using Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

Comment: did you try with `theme.appcompat.light`?

Comment: @njzk2 - I tried Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar but it still looks the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to define a custom theme like this:

```
<style name="Custom.SwitchCompat.WhiteTrack" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
        <!-- Inactive track color(30% transparency) -->
        <item name="android:colorForeground">[some color]</item>
    </style>
```

then define the theme in your layout like this:

```
android:theme="@style/Custom.SwitchCompat.WhiteTrack"
```

et voilà.